# C#のいい名前空間とクラス名とは？CreateObjectServiceはなんでだめなの？

Tags: c#

新人プログラマーです。

あるオブジェクトを生成するサービスの名前を、

> Hoge_Service.web.Services.CreateObjectService

と名付けたら、先輩に名前空間もクラス名もダメだと言われました。
いったい何がおかしいのでしょうか。

`質問時のメールアドレスを間違えて登録してしまいました。`

Comment: 名付けは慣習と感性、そして何より名前を付けたい対象が全体像のうちのどのような部分を成すのかを示す必要があります。つまり何が言いたいのかというと先輩がその答えを知っています。もし言語的感性を磨きたいという質問であれば、まずはProject名.Creationという名前を付けると何がまずいのかということをよくよく検討してみてください。

Answer (score 6):

.NET Frameworkには[名前付けのガイドライン](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)があります。この中に

> Do not use underscores to differentiate words, or for that matter, anywhere in identifiers.

とあり`Hoge_Service`について`_`で区切るべきではありません。

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word

とあり`web`についてパラメーター以外は大文字から始めるべきです。

---

[名前空間の名前](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces)には

> ```
> <Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
> ```

とあります。`Hoge_Service.web.Services`がこの名前付けルールに従っているとは言いがたいです。

---

[クラス名の名前](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces)には

> name classes and structs with nouns or noun phrases, using PascalCasing.

とあります。`CreateObjectService`では名詞や名詞句ではありません。`CreateObjectService`はむしろメソッド名に適切です。

Answer (score 2):

基本的なことは sayuri さんが書かれているんですが、クラス名についてはもう１個。

「あるオブジェクトを生成するサービス」と言うことですが、それに`Object`なんて名前を使っちゃったら、「別のオブジェクトを生成するサービス」に付ける名前はどうするんでしょうか?

`Object`なんて単語は(`String`や`Boolean`等々ではなく)`object`型(`System.Object`)に関わるものであることを明示したいときに(他に意味のある名前がどうしても見つからない時にだけ)使用するべき([Avoiding Language-Specific Names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions#avoiding-language-specific-names)より)です。

`Object`なんてなんでもありの単語は使わずに、「あるオブジェクト」の性質なり機能なりを表す単語を使うべきでしょう。

---

名前空間については、C# のプロジェクトに Java のパッケージ名用の命名規則をそのまま使っている会社もあったりしたんで、会社の決めたルールは Microsoft のルールに優先すると思わないといけないんですが…。

名前空間やクラス名ではないですが、こんなルールはあまり守られていません。

[General Naming Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions#word-choice)より

> **X DO NOT** use Hungarian notation.
>
> **X** ハンガリアン記法は使っちゃ**ダメ**。

Answer (score -1):

naoki fujita さんのおっしゃるとおりです。答えは先輩が知っています。ただ、人間関係が悪くなってしまい聞きづらい状況です。

言語的感性を磨きたいとうことではありません。
あのときの先輩の口ぶりからは名前空間やクラス名の付け方に一般的な規則があるような感じでしたので、ここで質問させていただきました。それはsayuriさんやOOPerさんにいただいた回答なのだと思います。

お二人からいただいた回答に従えば次のようになるのかと思います。

> Hoge.Service.Web.Services.SomethingCreationService

このように改めて書いてみると、名前空間にService、Servicesと同じ意味の単語があり、いい名前空間ではないと思います。これはnaoki fujitaさんがおっしゃる言語感性によるものかと思います。名前空間をどのように構築するかを熟慮できていないのだと思います。その名前空間の良し悪しは先輩に聞いてみたいと思います。

sayuriさん、OOPerさん、naoki fujitaさん、本当にありがとうございました。

`質問時に登録したメールアドレスを間違えてしまったようです。`

Comment: アカウントについてはこちらのヘルプトピック[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)をご参照ください。コメントが書けないせいで、あなたなりの「回答」(それが質問に対する回答になっているかどうか微妙ですが)と本来コメントにすべき内容が混ざりこんでしまっているようです。あなたが真摯に回答の内容やコメントの内容に答えようとしてくださっているのはわかるのですが、残念ながらこのサイトではそれは正しいやり方ではありません。(ちなみに「感性」「人間関係」などに突っ込んでしまうと、当サイトでは扱えないトピックということになります。[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))まずはアカウントの統合を依頼してみてください。それが完了するとご自身の質問が編集できるようになり、ご自身の質問についたコメントにコメントの形で返信することができるようになります。少々面倒に感じるかもしれませんが、「より良いQ&A集を蓄積することにより、あなたの経験を他の方々にも有用なものとする」ことを意図してできているルールです。その辺を意識して、うまくこのサイトを利用していってください。